# Access to component methods in React

Tags: reactjs

I'm using a component called [react-input-autosize](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-input-autosize). The issue I'm facing is that it won't resize the input on viewport resize, so I wan't to manually hook into the component methods and run `copyInputStyles()` and `updateInputWidth()`.

Pretty new to React so don't know how to achieve this. You can expose the input via the inputRef, but that doesn't really help me no?

My current reduced test case looks like this, would be happy with any pointers on how to run the component methods.

```
    import React from 'react';
    import styled from '@emotion/styled';
    import AutosizeInput from 'react-input-autosize';
    import {throttle} from 'lodash';


    const StyledAutosizeInput = styled(AutosizeInput)`
      max-width: 100vw;
    `;

    export default class signUp extends React.Component {
      constructor (props) {
        super(props);
        this.inputRef = React.createRef();
      }

      componentDidMount() {
        console.log(this.inputRef); // outputs input node
        window.addEventListener('resize', this.resize);
        this.resize();
      }

      componentWillUnmount() {
        window.removeEventListener('resize', this.resize);
      }

      resize = throttle(() => {
        console.log('force resize');
      }, 100);

      render() {
        return (
          <StyledAutosizeInput
            inputRef={node => this.inputRef = node}
          />
        );
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `inputRef={node => this.inputRef = node}` callback [is referring to the html input element](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-input-autosize/blob/05b0f86a7f8b16de99c2b31296ff0d3307f15957/src/AutosizeInput.js#L174) and not the AutosizeInput component. Pass the ref via the `ref` prop to access the component's methods.

```
...

resize = throttle(() => {
    if (this.inputRef.current) {
      this.inputRef.current.copyInputStyles()
      this.inputRef.current.updateInputWidth()
    }
  }, 100);

  render() {
    return (
      <StyledAutosizeInput
        ref={this.inputRef}
      />
    );
  }
```

Comment: Haha, I actually tried with `ref` before, but upon inspecting the output I didn't even bother trying to run the method as they weren't showing up there. Thank you!